# React way of grabbing a button element and using disable property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code where a user can select a file and hit upload and the `Choose` button is disabled.

Code Sanbox link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-chandrasekhar-qz9tg?file=/src/demo/FileUploadDemo.js:0-1993):

```
 import "primeicons/primeicons.css";
    import "primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";
    import "primereact/resources/primereact.css";
    import "primeflex/primeflex.css";
    import "../../index.css";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    
    import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
    import { FileUpload } from "primereact/fileupload";

export const FileUploadDemo = () => {
  const toast = useRef(null);
  const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = useState(false);

  const onUpload = () => {
    toast.current.show({
      severity: "info",
      summary: "Success",
      detail: "File Uploaded"
    });
  };

  const onTemplateAdvancedSelect = (e) => {
    console.log("Printing onTemplateAdvancedSelect ");
    console.log(e);
    let inputFileType = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
    //setDisableButton(true);
    inputFileType.classList.add("toDisableOnSelect");
    inputFileType.disabled = true;

    let htmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    );
    console.log("Printing htmlCollection");
    console.log(htmlCollection.length);
    console.log(htmlCollection);

    // htmlCollection.addEventListener("click", function () {
    //   inputFileType.disabled = false;
    // });
    //console.log(htmlCollection.item(19));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card">
        <h5>Advanced</h5>
        <FileUpload
          multiple={false}
          name="demo[]"
          url="https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/upload.php"
          onUpload={onUpload}
          id={"myId"}
          accept="image/*"
          maxFileSize={1000000}
          onSelect={onTemplateAdvancedSelect}
          disabled={disableButton}
          emptyTemplate={
            <p className="p-m-0">Drag and drop files to here to upload.</p>
          }
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<FileUploadDemo />, rootElement);
```

So Inside `onTemplateAdvancedSelect` function, I want to set  `inputFileType.disabled` to `false` once user hits the cross icon as shown below:

[image]

I don't want to use `getElementByClassName` just like I have attempted to use in my code of above function. What would be a better way to achieve my goal?

Primereact version I'm using : 4.2.2

Comment: where is exactly the `p-button p-component p-button-icon-only` element? is it inside your react components hierarchy?

Comment: @Heartbit If you select a file using Choose button and right click on the selected file to inspect it, you will see that. Please see this image screenshot with Inspect thing on Firefox : https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8mwB.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is customizing the row `item` of the selected file.
so the `itemTemplate` prop is exactly for that goal.

```js
export const FileUploadDemo = () => {
  const toast = useRef(null);
  const fileUploadRef = useRef(null) // reference to uploader node
  const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = useState(false);
  const onTemplateRemove = (file, callback) => {
        // setTotalSize(totalSize - file.size);
        const domInput = fileUploadRef.current.fileInput;
        domInput.disabled = false;
        callback();
  }
  const onTemplateAdvancedSelect = () => {
     const domInput = fileUploadRef.current.fileInput; // pure dome element
     domInput.disabled = true;
     
  }
  const itemTemplate = (file, props) => {
        return (
            <>
            <div>
                <img alt={file.name} role="presentation" src={file.src} width="50" />

            </div>
            <div class="p-fileupload-filename">{file.name}</div>
            <div>{file.size}</div>
            <div>
                { /* here you have access to that button */}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
                  onClick={() => onTemplateRemove(file, props.onRemove)}>
                    <span class="p-button-icon p-c pi pi-times"></span>
                    <span class="p-button-label p-c">&nbsp;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card">
        <h5>Advanced</h5>
        <FileUpload
          ref={fileUploadRef} // pass a reference for `input` manipulation
          multiple={false}
          name="demo[]"
          url="https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/upload.php"
          onUpload={onUpload}
          id={"myId"}
          accept="image/*"
          maxFileSize={1000000}
          /* here we should pass the customized template as prop */
          itemTemplate={itemTemplate} 
          onSelect={onTemplateAdvancedSelect}
          disabled={disableButton}
          emptyTemplate={
            <p className="p-m-0">Drag and drop files to here to upload.</p>
          }
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thank you!. One question - where should I set the property(`inputFileType.disabled = false;`) inside `itemTemplate` function  which I set to `true` inside `onTemplateAdvancedSelect` function?

Comment: I think I can do the following inside `onTemplateRemove()` function, like the following: ` const onTemplateRemove = (file, callback) => {
    // setTotalSize(totalSize - file.size);
    let inputFileType = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
    inputFileType.disabled = false;
    callback();
  };`

Comment: For some reason, it's not getting enabled again in my code after I used it like I mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: you should pass `ref` and do dom manipulation with that reference

Comment: Setting it to false inside `onTemplateRemove` function doesn't seem to be enabling the button after pressing cross icon. Here is what I did. Anything wrong I'm doing here? ` const onTemplateRemove = (file, callback) => {
        const domeInput = fileUploadRef.current.fileInput; // pure dome element
        domeInput.disabled = false;
        callback();
    }`

The way you modified inside `onTemplateAdvSelect` works fine for disabling the button. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't havd any effect on that button, you  just have a 'ref' to Input

Comment: Sorry I am little confused. The button seems to be getting disabled after using `domeInput.disabled = true`. However, I am wondering Where would I put ` const domeInput = fileUploadRef.current.fileInput; domeInput.disabled = false;` to enable it once user hit the cross icon of the button? Thanks!

Comment: sorry I did not get your point on pre comment, you are right

Comment: So does that mean there is no way to enable the button by setting `domeInput.disabled = false` somewhere once user hits the cross button? Thanks again!

Comment: I edited the part for `disabled = false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240725/discussion-between-tan-and-heartbit).

Answer (score 0):

Please use useRef hook provided by react. Example below:

```
function TextInputWithFocusButton() {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you answer in the context of my question? refs came to my mind but I am not sure how to use it to grab a button element which gets created on the fly and then work on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a getElementsByClassName. You can use the onRemove event to handle the file remove event.

```
<FileUpload
      multiple={false}
      name="demo[]"
      url="https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/upload.php"
      onUpload={onUpload}
      id={"myId"}
      accept="image/*"
      maxFileSize={1000000}
      onSelect={onTemplateAdvancedSelect}
      disabled={disableButton}
      emptyTemplate={
        <p className="p-m-0">Drag and drop files to here to upload.</p>
      }
      onRemove={(e, file) => setDisableButton(false)}
    />
```

Comment: This seems to be not working since I have set ` inputFileType.disabled = true;` inside `onTemplateAdvancedSelect` function. Please let me know if there is another way of handling my goal.Thanks!

Comment: I've tested in the sandbox you've shared and this worked fine.  Please have a look again.

Comment: Thanks. I think you were setting `setDisableButton(true)` somewhere in `onTemplateAdvancedSelect` function because I don't think I am using it anywhere in my sandbox even though i have declared it? One problem with this approach is that as soon as I select a file, it disables all the three buttons so a user won't be able to upload the selected file if he wants to. If you could share your version of modified sandbox with your solution, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand your use case. Do you want to remove the image from the upload stack by clicking the x button?

I think you should rather use the built-in API to trigger functionality. If that doesn't help you can extend the library.

Comment: `Do you want to remove the image from the upload stack by clicking the x button? ` Yes, and while doing that I want to set  `inputFileType.disabled` to `false` since it has been set to `true` inside `onTemplateAdvancedSelect` function when a user clicked the `Choose` button and selected a file.

Comment: Can you explain via code - how to use ref on `p-button p-component p-button-icon-only` inside `onTemplateRemove` ?

Comment: Ideally, you would use useRef but since you don't have access to `input[type=file]` it's ok to use querySelector. You can contribute to the lib to have a prop that is setting the input type to disabled.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `You can contribute to the lib to have a prop that is setting the input type to disabled.` ? Thanks !

Comment: I see there is a `disabled` property. I guess that's setting the input filed to disabled. Why don't you use that instead of imperatively setting the disabled property?

Comment: Can you put what you are saying in the code in your post? I am not sure if I am following you properly. Thanks!